# Pattern matching code for matching type of Some[x] is not reachable in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
val what: Option[Any] = Some("dab")

what match{
  case a : Some[Int] => "its int"
  case b : Some[String] => "its string"
  case None => "42"
}
```

This result to the warning 
Warning:(41, 29) unreachable code
  case b : Some[string] => "its string"
Can some expline me this warning

P.S: Ignoring the type erasure warning.
                           ^

Answer (score 1):

Thats because higher kinded types does not exist in runtime. I mean, in runtime that pattern matching bytecode wont be able to distinguish a Some[Int] from Some[String]. For it will be all Some[Any], and that´s the reason for the warning message.

Check some of the post which talk about: https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, generics are erased at runtime, which means that the runtime type of List[Int] and List[Boolean] is actually the same. This is called type erasure.
For more info [refer](https://blog.knoldus.com/2018/04/02/type-erasure-in-scala/#more-47783)

Answer (score 1):

You should not ignore the warning about type erasure, because that is what is causing the problem.

The Java runtime does not distinguish between different variants of `Some[T]` in this context, so `Some[Int]` matches any `Some[T]` and therefore `Some[String]` can never match.

To make this work you have to extract the contents of the `Option` and then match it, like this:

```
what match {
  case Some(x) => x match {
    case _: Int => "its int"
    case _: String => "its string"
  }
  case None => "42"
}
```

### Note

Although your code will compile, it will not do what you want. In particular, it will execute the first `case` for any non-empty `Option` value. If your code assumes that it is `Some[Int]` then you may get a runtime error if it is actually something else. These bugs can be hard to track, so it is important to heed any type erasure warnings.